# Delete elements at different indices in a text file

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi I am trying to read a line from a text file, the content is in the like this

```
#b.txt
[[11353, 11355, 6575, 8303, 6615, 9534, 6535, 9715, 8434, 70433, 67214, 6541, 10936, 9700], [68624, 68337, 68241, 68138, 70577, 10244, 14207, 14205, 14209, 14206, 8499, 14211, 14115], 0.04347332273773796, 0.3808054549485501] : 1.0
```

I want to delete unwanted elements`(, 0.04347332273773796, 0.3808054549485501] : 1.0)` in the line and read it back in the format shown below. Please how can I do that

```
[[11353, 11355, 6575, 8303, 6615, 9534, 6535, 9715, 8434, 70433, 67214, 6541, 10936, 9700], [68624, 68337, 68241, 68138, 70577, 10244, 14207, 14205, 14209, 14206, 8499, 14211, 14115]]
```

Comment: Can you give more detailed description? What is 'unwanted elements'?

Comment: @TankyWoo the unwanted elements are '0.04347332273773796, 0.3808054549485501] : 1.0'

Comment: Why are they unwanted? What is the rule to recognize them?

Comment: Can you give more details about how the file has been created? It does not look like any known format like JSON nor CSV... I'm afraid you'll have to play with regular expressions here.

Comment: The file is created of this format <class 'inspyred.ec.ec.Individual'> then I convert it to a string file and write to the text file

Comment: @Tichodromamuraria they are unwanted because I only need the list of list part for the further work I want to do

Comment: So you want to drop everything from the list that is not a list?

Comment: @Tichodroma yes please and return just the list of list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
s = "[[11353, 11355, 6575, 8303, 6615, 9534, 6535, 9715, 8434, 70433, 67214, 6541, 10936, 9700], [68624, 68337, 68241, 68138, 70577, 10244, 14207, 14205, 14209, 14206, 8499, 14211, 14115], 0.04347332273773796, 0.3808054549485501] : 1.0]"

l = [l for l in eval(s.split(":")[0]) if type(l) == type([])]
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[[11353, 11355, 6575, 8303, 6615, 9534, 6535, 9715, 8434, 70433, 67214, 6541, 10936, 9700], [68624, 68337, 68241, 68138, 70577, 10244, 14207, 14205, 14209, 14206, 8499, 14211, 14115]]
```

Comment: thanks this works perfectly. I appreciate your help. Kindly vote my question.